# A distribution $\pi \propto \exp(-f)$ satisfies log-Sobolev inequality, does $\exp(-af)$ also satisfy LSI?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, probability-distributions, inequalities, entropy

Assume a distribution $\pi \propto e^{-f}$ satisfies log-Sobolev inequality (LSI)
$$\forall \rho \in P(\mathbb{R}^n), \quad KL(\rho\| \pi) \le \frac{1}{2\lambda} I(\rho \| \pi)$$
with LSI constant $\lambda$. $KL(\rho\| \pi)$ is the KL-divergence, and $I (\rho\| \pi)$ is the relative Fisher information.

If $a>0$, does $\bar\pi  \propto e^{-af}$ also satisfy LSI?

If yes, what would be the new LSI constant?

As far as I know, if $Hessian(f) \ge \lambda I_n$, i.e. $f$ is strongly concave, then $\bar\pi  \propto e^{-af}$ satisfies LSI with constant $a\lambda$. But how about other more genearal cases?